# Android, how to measure an elapsed amount of time

Tags: android

I'm working on a presentation app, which displays different images. There I wanted to to let the presentation slide through my List of images, video and pdf files, after a short amount of time.

I start my different views through intents, `startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_OK);`

Starting videos and closing videos was not an issue. I used `onPreparedListener` and `setOnCompletionListener` and everything worked like a charm.

With pictures however, this was completely diffrent.

I created a new `Thread` in my `ImageView` and did put that thread to `sleep()`, after that I called the `setresult()` method and `finish()`. But instead of waiting, the picture wasn't shown at all and the presentation was stuck there, without setting the result and finishing the activity.

So I started searching for some explanation of time in android and found this explanation:

[Explanation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#uptimeMillis%28%29)

I read through it and tried to get a good grasp on whats explained there. But the more I thought about it, the more I got insecure, which is the best way to implement the waiting behavior for my intended purpose.

So instead of some code, I am much more interested in, what you would advise me to use and why with a, if possible, detailed explanation.

1. `elapsedRealtime()`?
2. `uptimeMillis()`?
3. `System.currentTimeMillis()`?

Comment: What excatly do you want to achieve? You want to change images in ImageView after specified amount of time elapsed?

Comment: exactly, if the next List element is another image I want the ImageView to wait and then to display is, else to close and return the RESULT_OK to my Presentation and let the presentation, continue, or finish depending on if there are further images, video, etc. left in my list

Comment: What you want is a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to achieve that is `CountDownTimer`

```
private final class CountDownTimerImpl extends CountDownTimer {
    //5 sec.
    private static final long TIME_INTERVAL = 5000;
    private final ImageView imageView;
    private final List<Drawable> images;

    public CountDownTimerImpl(ImageView imageView, List<Drawable> images) {
        super(TIME_INTERVAL, TIME_INTERVAL);
        this.imageView = imageView;
        this.images = images;

        //set first image from images array to imageView
        imageView.setImageDrawable(images.get(0));
    }       

    //this method is executed after TIME_INTERVAL (5 sec.)
    public void onFinish() {
        //remove drawable from imageView
        imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
        //remove this drawable from array
        images.remove(0);
        //if array is not empty start another count down
        if (!images.isEmpty()) {
            new CountDownTimerImpl(imageView, images).start();
        }
    }

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        //nothing to do here
    }
}
```

You should start this CountDownTimer by:

```
new CountDownTimerImpl(imageView, images).start();
```

where `images` is of course an drawables array of your presentation images.

I have no time to test this solution but it should work - if not please leave a comment and I will update it later.

Comment: I like this solution a lot! Tried to implement the expected  behavior, using Handlers and Intents, but it didn't work like expected. I got often NoMemoryErrors, or the BitmapFactory crashed, etc ... Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

From android docs:

> • System.currentTimeMillis() is the standard "wall" clock (time and date) expressing milliseconds since the epoch. The wall clock can be set by the user or the phone network (see setCurrentTimeMillis(long)), so the time may jump backwards or forwards unpredictably. This clock should only be used when correspondence with real-world dates and times is important, such as in a calendar or alarm clock application. Interval or elapsed time measurements should use a different clock. If you are using System.currentTimeMillis(), consider listening to the ACTION_TIME_TICK, ACTION_TIME_CHANGED and ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED Intent broadcasts to find out when the time changes.
>
> • uptimeMillis() is counted in milliseconds since the system was booted. This clock stops when the system enters deep sleep (CPU off, display dark, device waiting for external input), but is not affected by clock scaling, idle, or other power saving mechanisms. This is the basis for most interval timing such as Thread.sleep(millls), Object.wait(millis), and System.nanoTime(). This clock is guaranteed to be monotonic, and is suitable for interval timing when the interval does not span device sleep. Most methods that accept a timestamp value currently expect the uptimeMillis() clock.
>
> • elapsedRealtime() and elapsedRealtimeNanos() return the time since the system was booted, and include deep sleep. This clock is guaranteed to be monotonic, and continues to tick even when the CPU is in power saving modes, so is the recommend basis for general purpose interval timing.

If the time interval, you're going to measure, is relatively short, you can use pretty much any method which gives you correct time. I prefer currentTimeMillis(). In case the time interval is really long, the recommended method is to use elapsedRealtime().

Also, if you only want to do something with a delay, simply use: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable, long) . It's simple and works great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TimerTask

```
int counter=0;   
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Timer ourtimer = new Timer();
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
      public void run() {
              handler.post(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
counter++;
              //you can do stuffs here say  like if (counter==15) { do something}


                      }
             });
      }};


ourtimer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a different way writing a callback module

Create a activity call it BaseActivity and let all you activities to extend it
Now declare a method call is `void callback(){}` keep the body empty

now in onCreate create a timer as above and call the callback function your code will look like

```
onCreate(){
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Timer callTimer = new Timer();
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
      public void run() {
              handler.post(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
            callback();


                      }
             });
      }};


callTimer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 1000);
}
```

Now in you activity override the callback method which will be called after the time you specified in timer,

Ex

```
Class a extends BaseActivity(){

@Override 
 onCreate(){
// playVideo
}

@Override 

void onCallBack(){
 //navigate to another activity
}

}
```